# Java check input is integer or empty to allow for default value

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently trying to make a fairly basic java program that asks users for input and if they hit enter to provide a default value.

At the moment my code to do this is

```
System.out.println("Please enter a port number (default 8080): ")
port = scanner.nextLine();
      if (port.isEmpty() || port.equals("8080")) {
          port = "8080";
          System.out.println("Using default port...");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Using new port...");
      }
```

I would like to alter this to check that the input (if there is any) is an integer and if not, loop back round to ask for input again. I know it needs to use a combination of hasNextInt and nextLine but I cannot figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing around with nextInt() I would suggest trying to parse the input as an integer and handle the exception if it fails

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a port number (default 8080): ");
String port = null;
while (true) {
    port = scanner.nextLine();
    if (port.isEmpty() || port.equals("8080")) {
        port = "8080";
        break;
    } else {
        try {
            Integer.valueOf(port);
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect value given, try again");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("You have selected " + port);
scanner.close();
```

Comment: That works perfectly for what I am trying to do, thank you so much!

Comment: You don't have to check the extra `port.equals("8080")` condition.

Comment: @ZainArshad true, I just left that part unchanged

Answer (score 0):

This would be one option. You simply ask the user a couple of times to enter default and if they fail more than a few times, you return the default port. If the input they provide is not an Integer, an InputMismatchException is thrown and we tell them its incorrect, then we either make another attempt or return default.

It is worth noting we call Scanner#next() to clear the underlying cache to remove any existing data.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int port = askForPortOr(scanner, 8080, 0, 3);

        System.out.println("port: " + port);
    }

    private static int askForPortOr(Scanner scanner, int defaultPort, int attempts, int maximumAttempts) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a port number (default 8080): ");
            return scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            scanner.next();

            if (++attempts < maximumAttempts) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect port, please try again...");
                return askForPortOr(scanner, defaultPort, attempts, maximumAttempts);
            }
            return defaultPort;
        }
    }
```

Output

```
Please enter a port number (default 8080): 
808o
Incorrect port, please try again...
Please enter a port number (default 8080): 
808o
Incorrect port, please try again...
Please enter a port number (default 8080): 
808o
port: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use java Regex

```
if (port.matches("\\d+")) {
  System.out.println("it's a natural number (positive integer)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
String port;
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     do {
     System.out.println("Please enter a port number (default 8080): ");
     port = scanner.nextLine();
           if (port.isEmpty() || port.equals("8080")) {
               port = "8080";
               System.out.println("Using default port...");
           }     
 }while(!port.matches("\\d*"));
```